# Callback for MSSticker Peels in iOS 10 iMessage sticker app

Tags: swift, ios-app-extension, ios10, imessage

I'm experimenting with sticker iMessage apps in iOS 10 and I'm running into an issue with the `override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)` method in `MSMessagesAppViewController`. When "peeling" a sticker from an `MSStickerView`, I would expect to receive some sort of callback on the `didStartSending` method. But it appears this is not the case. Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior and/or if there's another way to subscribe to callbacks for when these stickers are peeled, dragged, and dropped into the `MSConversation`? I realize that `didStartSending` is reserved for when the user taps the send button, but surely there should be *some* way of knowing when users drag MSStickers without hacking together some UIView dragging/rect-reading heuristic.

Messages View Controller:

```
class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {

    var nYCStickersBroswerViewController: NYCStickersBroswerViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nYCStickersBroswerViewController = NYCStickersBroswerViewController(stickerSize: .regular)
        nYCStickersBroswerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        self.addChildViewController(nYCStickersBroswerViewController)
        nYCStickersBroswerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.view.addSubview(nYCStickersBroswerViewController.view)

        nYCStickersBroswerViewController.loadStickers()
        nYCStickersBroswerViewController.stickerBrowserView.reloadData()
    }

    ...

    override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the user taps the send button.
        print(message) // should this not contain the sticker that is peeled, dragged, and dropped into the conversation?
    }

 }
```

Sticker Browser:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Messages

class ASSticker: MSSticker {
    var identifier: String?
}

class NYCStickersBroswerViewController: MSStickerBrowserViewController {

    var stickers = [ASSticker]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func changeBrowswerViewBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = color
    }

    func loadStickers() {
        createSticker(name: "brooklyn", localizedDescription: "Brooklyn Bridge Sticker")
        createSticker(name: "liberty", localizedDescription: "Statue of Liberty Sticker")
        createSticker(name: "love", localizedDescription: "I Love New York Sticker")
        createSticker(name: "mets", localizedDescription: "New York Mets Sticker")
        createSticker(name: "rangers", localizedDescription: "New York Rangers Sticker")
        createSticker(name: "subway", localizedDescription: "New York City MTA Subway Train Sticker")
    }

    func createSticker(name: String, localizedDescription: String) {
        guard let stickerPath = Bundle.main.pathForResource(name, ofType: "png") else {
            print("Call ae cab, you're intoxicated.")
            return
        }
        let stickerURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: stickerPath)
        let sticker: ASSticker
        do {
            try sticker = ASSticker(contentsOfFileURL: stickerURL, localizedDescription: localizedDescription)
            sticker.identifier = "something unique"
            stickers.append(sticker)
        } catch {
            print("Call a cab, you're intoxicated.")
        }
    }

    override func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
        return self.stickers.count
    }
    override func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
        return self.stickers[index]
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey did you ever get this to work? I am having the same issue

Comment: The answers below are great work arounds, but I've yet to come up with a solution using the stock `MSStickerBrowserViewController`.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a subclass and delegate that will tie into the tap and long press gesture recognizers that `MSStickerView` is using for select and peel interactions. If the implementation of `MSStickerView` changes this may no longer provide events, but shouldn't crash.

```
import UIKit
import Messages

protocol InstrumentedStickerViewDelegate: class {
    func stickerViewDidSelect(stickerView: MSStickerView)
    func stickerViewDidPeel(stickerView: MSStickerView)
}

class InstrumentedStickerView: MSStickerView {
    weak var delegate: InstrumentedStickerViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        for gestureRecognizer in gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
            if let tapGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
                tapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap))
            } else if let longPressGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
                longPressGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didLongPress))
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func didTap(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if tapGestureRecognizer.state == .Recognized {
            delegate?.stickerViewDidSelect(self)
        }
    }

    func didLongPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
            delegate?.stickerViewDidPeel(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, how would you use this i.e. if I have stickers, how can I use these callback functions in my class?

Comment: A usage example would be really helpful

Comment: Great solution! @skyguy to use, just replace your MSStickerView with InstrumentedStickerView and make sure to set the delegate property to your class that implements InstrumentedStickerViewDelegate: `stickerView.delegate = self`

Comment: If I want to "steal" the gestures only on certain conditions, where would I have to forward the gestures to to enable  select and peel interaction?

Comment: Double tap on the sticker hangs the application in expnded mode. Does any one can help?

Comment: @Hilton Is this Appstore safe?

Comment: I've used it in two apps on the App Store without rejection.

Comment: @HiltonCampbell How do I replace MSStickerView with InstrumentedStickerView?. I am currently using MSStickerBrowserViewController and cannot figure out a way to replace the MSStickerView

Comment: I created my own view controller using a `UICollectionView` instead of using `MSStickerBrowserViewController`.

Comment: @HiltonCampbell I wanted to add in-App purchase on the sticker is this possible to add and pop up for purchase the sticker?

Comment: Assuming you've created a custom UI, I think you could cover the sticker with a transparent button and respond to that to display the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for sticker peeled and tapped events, it is not guaranteed that a particular sticker will be inserted but an approximation of such data points - you will have to use your subclass of MSStickerView. This solution is not futureproof, but works for the time being IMHO, therefore I welcome other ideas.

```
import UIKit
import Messages

class CustomStickerView : MSStickerView{
    class GestureRecognizerReceiver : NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
    let _recognizerDelegate = GestureRecognizerReceiver()

    weak var _recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil
    func setupTapRecognizer(){
        if _recognizer == nil {
            let r = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(_customTapReceived))
            r.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            r.delegate = _recognizerDelegate
            addGestureRecognizer(r)
            _recognizer = r
    }
}

    func _customTapReceived(){
        if let s = sticker{
            Analytics.shared.reportEvent(name: "Sticker Inserted", description: s.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let s = sticker{
            Analytics.shared.reportEvent(name: "Sticker Peeled", description: s.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let sv = CustomStickerView(frame: _stickerViewHolder.bounds, sticker: sticker)
sv.setupTapRecognizer()
_stickerViewHolder.addSubview(sv)
sv.startAnimating()
```