# Is it possible to identify what sticker was assigned to your iMessage Extension?

Tags: ios, imessage, ios-extensions, imessage-extension, mssticker

We need to implement iMessage application with the possibility to assign ratings to the messages. Are there any possible way to do it with stickers?

Does iMessage extensions API allow to identify what sticker has been assigned to the sent message? If so are there are any limitation - about that the sticker must be the part of the same application or your extension can identify stickers from other extension.

Comment: You get only messages sent by your application. You get informed by delegate messages. For instance `didStartSending`, which also gives you  the `MSConversaton` and the `MSMessage`. Check Apples sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for response, I can see that `didStartSending` is throwing immediately after pushing send button, but the event is not thrown when I'm assigning sticker on the message. I'm looking for the delegate (or other possible way) which can inform that my `MSSticker` was assigned to my `MSMessage`

Comment: I probably misunderstood "...what sticker has been assigned to the sent message...". As only you can set a `MSSticker` to a `MSMessage`, you are the only one that knows when this happens.

Comment: 1.I've sent a message (`MSMessage`). 2.Opponent receives a message (he see the message in the list). 3.Opponent puts sticker (`MSSticker` - Like or Dislike) on the message (drag and drops, sticker from the same application). Q. Are there any possible way to identify what sticker my opponent put to my message?

Comment: I found similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441987/callback-for-mssticker-peels-in-ios-10-imessage-sticker-app. May be it can help me

Comment: Check out the IceCreamBuilder sample code mentioned above. It does exact the same thing, but with ice cream instead of like/dislike.